# Resource folder got "Excluded" from solution explorer in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resources, solution-explorer

I am working on a C# desktop application in Visual Studio 2008.
While I was working, I intended to add a new item to the `"Resources"` folder by right clicking it, but I accidentally clicked `"Exclude from project"` and it started processing and the folder is no more visible in my solution explorer.

How to re-include that folder in my project, and just out of curiosity, what can be the effects of it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the Solution Explorer is a (Toggle-)MenuItem "Show All Files".

When you active the MenuItem, then should all files and folders be displayed that are in the directory of the solution.

Your "Resources" folder should be presented with a white folder symbol. Do a Right-Click on the folder and select "Include in project"-Option.

After that the "Resources"-Directory is again part of your project.